flutter After windowManager.setResizable(reset) is called, no matter reset is true or false, the window size cannot be changed
    windowManager.waitUntilReadyToShow(windowOptions, () async {
        await windowManager.setTitleBarStyle(TitleBarStyle.hidden,
            windowButtonVisibility: butenBool);
        await windowManager.focus();
        await windowManager.setResizable(reSize);
        await windowManager.show();
    });

I want to not be able to resize the window when I log in, but I can resize it again when I go to the homepage, but I found that I can't change the window size as long as I call windowManager.setResizable.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        print("Setting resizable to false");
       await windowManager.setResizable(false);
       print("Resizable set to false");
    });

It won’t work if you write the method until after the page is loaded.
